# What is rotating the preview in the Android sample "CameraPreview"?

Tags: android

The sample in question is: [CameraPreview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html)

I was wondering what piece of code is making the preview become rotated 90 degrees to the left? I'm certain there's something very obvious I'm overlooking but I just can't seem to find the culprit. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApiDemos [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/AndroidManifest.html) file has `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` set for the `CameraPreview` activity.

Comment: I've actually copied the code from the sample into my own project and have the screenOrientation set to portrait. I've found though, if I remove that tag, when I change my phone to landscape, the image is correctly displayed (albeit a bit squished, but I think that has to do with the getOptimalPreviewSize method).

Thanks.